# Как получить количество детей в каждой школе из базы данных на C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

У меня есть база данных в ms sql server. В ней есть таблички "Список детей" и "Список образовательных учреждений".

В таблице "Список детей" есть поля "id ребёнка", "ФИО" и "id Образовательного учреждения".
В таблице "Образовательные учреждения" есть поля "id образовательного учреждения" и "название".

Так вот, мне нужно посчитать, сколько детей учится в школе №1, и сохранить этот список детей. Затем нужно посчитать сколько детей учится в школе №2, и сохранить этот список детей. И так до тех пор, пока не закончится список школ.

Пишу на C#, уже несколько дней ломаю голову, как можно это сделать. Подозреваю, что можно как-то через запросы linq сделать, но так и не дошло как.

Вот как-то так я пытался уже нарешать

```
var ListChildren = ВедущийСпециалистEntities.GetContext().СписокДетей.ToList();
            var CountChildren = ListChildren.Count();

            var ListObrUch = ВедущийСпециалистEntities.GetContext().ОбразовательныеУчреждения.ToList();

            List<string> listRebenok = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in ListChildren)
            {
                //тройка - это id одного из образовательных учреждений
                if (item.КодОрганизации == 3)
                {
                    listRebenok.Add(Convert.ToString(item));
                }
            }
```

Comment: все очень просто. 1) делаешь SQL запрос и получаешь список школ. 2) проходишься по этому списку в цикле и "отсеиваешь" детей (с помощью `where`), нужных детей добавляешь в другой список. 3) считаешь количество элементов в списке с детьми

Comment: А не можно сделать  `select ФИОРебенка from  СписокДетей where idобразовательногоучреждения=<id учреждения>`, в цикле добавляешь детей в массив, потом со списком можно что угодно делать, в т.ч получить длину списка

Comment: ну а запрос в СписокДетей тоже в цикле пока не кончился список школ

Comment: Уточните вопрос. / Проще всего ваша задача решается одним sql-запросом. / `ВедущийСпециалистEntities.GetContext()` - это что такое? Linq2Sql? Entity Framework?

Comment: @Alexander БД была подключена через ADO.NET, и, как я понимаю, ВедущийСпециалистEntities.GetContext() - это обращение к самой базе. Извините, если что-то не правильно говорю, просто не силён в языке